# Show 1 Count for Percentage

Tags: sql-server

Since I am using my Union statement, I am getting a different row returned for each city in each individual database.  I only want ONE row returned from each database.  BUT if I use the SUM() function on my % it greatly skews the percentage.  What can I do in my query to accurately return the percentage from both tables and only have ONE row per city return?

```
Select City, Sum([Hospital In 50 Miles]), [% Where Hospital In 50 Miles]
FROM (
    Select city, count(case when in50 = 'Yes' then hospID else null end) As   [Hospital In 50 Miles],
    CAST(COUNT(case when in50 = 'Yes' then hospID else null end)*1/Count(case when in50 is not null then in50 else null end) as decimal(10,4)) As [% Where Hospital In 50 Miles]
    from database1
    where in50 is not null
    UNION ALL
    Select city, count(case when in50 = 'Yes' then hospID else null end) As [Hospital In 50 Miles],
    CAST(COUNT(case when in50 = 'Yes' then hospID else null end)*1/Count(case when in50 is not null then in50 else null end) as decimal(10,4)) As [% Where Hospital In 50 Miles]
    from database2
    where in50 is not null
  ) as
  Group by city
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't SUM averages, you have to SUM the components and average them.   Like this:

```
Select City, Sum([Hospital In 50 Miles]), 
Sum([Hospital In 50 Miles])/SUM([Hospitals]) AS [% Where Hospital In 50 Miles]
FROM (
    Select city, count(case when in50 = 'Yes' then hospID else null end) As   [Hospital In 50 Miles],
    CAST(Count(case when in50 is not null then in50 else null end) as decimal(10,4)) As [Hospitals]
    from database1
    where in50 is not null
    UNION ALL
    Select city, count(case when in50 = 'Yes' then hospID else null end) As [Hospital In 50 Miles],
    CAST(Count(case when in50 is not null then in50 else null end) as decimal(10,4)) As [Hospitals]
    from database2
    where in50 is not null
  ) as
  Group by city
```

It may require some additional formatting of the output, but that's the basic structure.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put a total column in each of your subqueries, so you have something like

```
SELECT  City,
        In50 = COUNT(CASE WHEN In50 = 'Yes' THEN 1 END),
        Total = COUNT(*)
FROM    Database1
WHERE   In50 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY City
```

Then your % calculation is just `SUM(In50) / SUM(Total)`:

```
SELECT  City,
        In50 = SUM(In50),
        PercentIn50 = 1.0 * SUM(In50) / SUM(Total)
        Total = SUM(Total)
FROM    (
            SELECT  City,
                    In50 = COUNT(CASE WHEN In50 = 'Yes' THEN 1 END),
                    Total = COUNT(*)
            FROM    Database1
            WHERE   In50 IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY City
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  City,
                    In50 = COUNT(CASE WHEN In50 = 'Yes' THEN 1 END),
                    Total = COUNT(*)
            FROM    Database2
            WHERE   In50 IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY City
        ) AS t
GROUP BY City;
```

*N.B. I have added the missing group by clauses that would have caused your query to fail, and removed redundant checks, such as `COUNT(CASE WHEN In50 IS NOT NULL THEN In50 ELSE NULL END)` - this is not necessary since you already have `WHERE In50 IS NOT NULL` in the where clause*